# How much G-Force do people transported by the Flash experience?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014, science

How much is estimated g-force experienced by people grabbed and moved by Flash, and many times does it exceed fatal dose of (around) 65g?

Why don't these people die because if the G-force?

Comment: Nobody has been shown to die (or even suffer any real effects) from being moved at speed, so I'd assume it never approaches a fatal amount. I'd assume that whatever aspect of the Speed Force protects Barry from G-forces also applies to anything/anybody he's in contact with.

Comment: This will help understand Flash physics http://comicvine.gamespot.com/barry-allen/4005-22804/forums/flash-max-speed-704188/

Comment: Yeah, it's basically the same reason Superman can pick up an iceberg without ending up with an iceberg-size pile of ice-cubes.  Super powers extend beyond the body in non-obvious ways.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-force#Horizontal_axis_g-force

Horizontal g's can be tolerated much more easily. However, the victims would go blind instantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Speedforce allows the Flash, and by extension, people he carries, to ignored things like relativity, acceleration, and the environmental destruction that would normally be associated with moving at Mach speeds in atmosphere.

Comment: So, is it 0gs then? Or is there, say 0.5g, 1g, or some other non-lethal amount of acceleration on people he carries?

Comment: There's no answer to this.

The Speedforce allows him to vary all those factors, so it could be any of the above.